# reading data back from VBO on iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, vbo

My app writes all of my geometry data to VBO's for performance, but I need to read the vertex data during the program execution for ray triangle intersection testing. I noticed that there is a function that is supposed to map to the location of the VBO data, glMapBufferOES, but it looks like it only supports GL_READ_ONLY. Does anyone know of a way to read back VBO data on the iPhone once it's bound?

Comment: I have never seen such a function.  It would be expensive to read the VBO back if it has been loaded into GPU memory and discarded by the driver. How many vertices do you have?

Comment: 3 million vertices, but spread over 950 models. The problem I'm running into is if I upload my VBO for performance, then I don't have enough RAM on the iPhone and iPad to keep the vertices in a local array as well. The only way to display my large object is to have only one copy of the vertices. If I don't do VBO, then rendering speed is unacceptable. I'm using color ID to only do ray triangle testing on a single model each time the check is performed, which is only occasionally.

Comment: Any read operation on the tile-based deferred renderers of the iOS devices will be terribly slow because it halts the rendering pipeline (you might drop your framerate by over 20% by doing this).  Additionally, won't you just cause memory to spike too high by reloading the geometry while the VBO is still present on the GPU?

Comment: I assume the vertices aren't static and you can't memory-map them.  Is this the case?

Comment: The vertices are static, I don't need to modify them during execution, just read the values back so I can perform intersection testing. How would I go about memory mapping the vertices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. Since I'm not doing this every frame, I just read the vertices for the model I selected back from the file that I originally read in, perform ray triangle intersection testing, then clear the vertex array again. On small models the delay is imperceptible. On 1 million polygons, there is a half second delay, which is acceptable for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Save the filename so that you can load the vertices in from the file when you need it, do your testing, and then clear it again. This is along the lines of what Apple instructs you to do as much as you can when it comes to developing for iOS devices. The storage is surprisingly fast.

Comment: Glad to hear we both came to the same conclusion. It's much faster than I expected it would be.